# How can I make sure a function only SELECTs from one specific schema?

Tags: postgresql, database-permissions

What do I need to do to make sure that `sandbox.execute_any_query()` only `SELECT`s from tables in schema `sandbox`?

```sql
create function sandbox.execute_any_query(_query text) returns json as 
$$
declare
    _result json;
begin
    execute format('select row_to_json(t) from (%s) t', _query) into _result;
    return _result;
end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: the language name is an identifier. It shouldn't be quoted with single quotes. You should use `language plpgsql` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark the function as `SECURITY DEFINER` and make sure that the function owner does not have permissions on any schema other than `sandbox`.

Then the function will run in the user context of the owner, and any attempt to access other schemas will cause an error.

Comment: Adding a `set search_path = sandbox` to the function definition would also make sure that unqualified tables are used from the sandbox schema by default. Not really necessary but a convenience for the users calling the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally got it.